# Save CMD log to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pipe

Is there any way to save all the console output from command.exe or powershell to a file at the end of a session rather than piping each individual output?

I'm trying to save the output of an application that I run from a batch script that crashes when redirected but works fine when printing to the terminal.

This is okay; all output prints to console:

```
C:\TestPlatform\executables> TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64
```

All of the below produce no output; Program returns after 1-2 seconds instead of the 15-20 it should:

```
PS C:\TestPlatform\executables> TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64 | tee LogFile.txt

PS C:\TestPlatform\executables> TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64 | out-file -append LogFile.txt

C:\TestPlatform\executables> TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64 > logFile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Does the `TestApp.exe` executable use a file named `LogFile.txt`? Have you tried using `Out-File` instead of `Tee-Object` in PowerShell?

Comment: No I'm trying to pipe the output of TestApp.exe to a file called LogFile.txt. Which part is unclear about my question- I can try to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce however it is possible that redirection doesn't work for your exe because all text after the last switch is considered as arg to that switch so the exe consumes everything on the line till the last character - this would explain also why it doesn't run normally.
Try this alternative of logging in cmd:

```
C:\TestPlatform\executables>> logFile.txt 2>&1 TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64
```

Note the redirection character right after the prompt.

Comment: No luck with that either. I'll try to gain access to the source and see if I can find out what's going on.

Comment: The parser sticks the redirection to the end again (run with `echo on` to verify). Another trick, that *might*  work: `(TestApp.exe -c off -d file -q otp 47f64)>logfile.txt`

Comment: @Stephan I could not reproduce it at the  command prompt but with a file it does what you say. Parentheses as you suggest should address the issue (works for my test).

Comment: @Dávid: the command prompt does not have command repetition - so nothing to see here. Command repetition only works within batch files (if not disabled by `@`  or `echo off`)

Comment: @Stephan Ah, OK, I thought one can force it somehow with a session setting - I never needed such thing however. Thanks anyway, good to know!